# Multiple substitutions of numbers in string using regex python

Tags: python, regex, string

When i changed two words in a string with other two words using re.sub i got the output. But when i tried that with numbers output is not coming correctly

```
>>> import re
>>> a='this is the string i want to change'
>>> re.sub('(.*)is(.*)want(.*)','\\1%s\\2%s\\3' %('was','wanted'),a)
'this was the string i wanted to change'
>>> re.sub('(.*)is(.*)want(.*)','\\1%s\\2%s\\3' %('was','12345'),a)
'this was\x8a345 to change'
>>>
```

i don't know why this happens could u please tel me how to use this 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What happens is that you're passing in the replacement `r'\1was\212345\3'`, and Python cannot determine whether you want the backreference number 2, 21, 211, ... . It just picks the largest one, 212345, which is obviously not a group index in your expression. Therefore, Python decides you meant the bytestring literal `b'\212'`, which is a strange way of writing the `b'\x8a'`.

To resolve the ambiguity, use the long backreference syntax, `\g<GROUP_NUMBER_HERE>`:

```
>>> re.sub('(.*)is(.*)want(.*)','\\g<1>%s\\g<2>%s\\g<3>' %('was','12345'),a)
'this was the string i 12345 to change'
```